# Python import error "module 'factory' has no attribute 'fuzzy'"

Tags: python, testing, python-import, factory-boy

I'm a new to [factory_boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module. In my code, I `import factory` and then used this import to access the fuzzy attribute with `factory.fuzzy` then it throws error `module 'factory' has no attribute 'fuzzy'`.

I solved this problem by again importing like this 
`import factory
from factory import fuzzy`

by doing so there were no errors.

What is the reason for this!

Comment: are you sure about that. Please try it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Why this happens?

When you import a Python module (your `import factory`), you can then access directly what is declared in that module (e.g `factory.Factory`): all symbols declared in the module are automatically exported.

However, if a nested module is not imported in its parent, you have to import it directly.

Here, `factory.Factory` is available, because `factory/__init__.py` contains:

```py
from .base import Factory
```

=> When you type `factory.Factory`, Python looks up the symbol named `Factory` in `factory/__init__.py`, which is (per the above line) a reference to the `Factory` class defined in `factory/base.py`.

Since there is no line with `from . import fuzzy` in `factory/__init__.py`, Python cannot load it this way.

#### But why don't you add this line?

Other modules in the factory_boy package have dependencies on third-party packages;
for instance, `factory.django` imports Django. If `factory/__init__.py` contained the `from . import django` line (required to have `factory.django` available from `import factory`), every program that runs `import factory` would require to have Django installed.

In order to allow users of the package to decide what they depend on, the choice was made to not add those direct imports at the package top-level when possible — this allows for future versions to add external dependencies without breaking existing code.